# ArrayList is losing my reference

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist, synchronization

I have a static ArrayList (masterLog) that is in my main driver class. The ArrayList contains Event objects, the Event object has an `ArrayList (heats)` as a global variable. the heat object as an `ArrayList (racers)` as a global variable.  Now when I have the following line of code:

> System.out.println(ChronoTimer1009System.getMasterLog().get(0).getHeats().get(getCurHeat()).getRacers().toString());

this returns `[]` even though the `getRacers()` IS NOT empty!

When I call this:

```
System.out.println(getHeats().get(getCurHeat()).getRacers());
```

this returns the proper filled array.

I think I need to sync the masterLog ArrayList but I am unsure how.  I have tried syncing it the way other threads on Stack Exchange have recommended but no luck.

it seems like the static ArrayList masterLog is updated two levels deep but not three levels deep if that makes sense.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Maybe this will help explain:

In my main (driver) class, I have a static ArrayList called masterLog.  The purpose of this ArrayLIst is to store instances of Event objects for later data retrieval.  Now, without making it too complicated, the Event class contains an ArrayList called heats, and the Heat class contains an ArrayList called racers.  When I access the masterLog ArrayList at some point in the program (when the other ArrayLists are populated with data), say for example by the call "masterLog.getHeats().get(0).getRacers()", the masterLog does not find any data in the racers ArrayList.  It does, however, find data in the heats ArrayList.  In other words, the object instance that is stored in the masterLog only updates information to a depth of 2 (not 3 if that makes sense).

UPDATE:

Here is some code:

ChronoTimer1009System class (driver)

```
package main;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class ChronoTimer1009System {

private Event curEvent;
private static Channel[] channels = new Channel[8];
private boolean state;
private static Stack<Log> log;
private  static ArrayList<Event> masterLog;
private static Printer p;
public static Time globalTime;
private int oldLogSize; //used only in this.export()

public ChronoTimer1009System() throws UserErrorException{
    for(int i=0; i<channels.length; ++i){channels[i] = new Channel(SensorType.NONE);}  // initialize channels
    masterLog = new ArrayList<Event>(); //this holds references to each event
    this.newEvent(EventType.IND);
    this.state = false; //system is initally off
    log = new Stack<Log>();
    p = new Printer();
    globalTime = null;
    oldLogSize = 0;
}

public void newEvent(EventType e) throws UserErrorException {
    switch(e){
        case IND: this.curEvent = new IND();ChronoTimer1009System.masterLog.add(this.curEvent);break;
        case PARIND: this.curEvent = new PARIND();ChronoTimer1009System.masterLog.add(this.curEvent);break;
        case GRP: this.curEvent = new GRP();ChronoTimer1009System.masterLog.add(this.curEvent);break;
        case PARGRP: this.curEvent = new PARGRP();ChronoTimer1009System.masterLog.add(this.curEvent);break;
    }
    for(Channel x : channels){if(x.getState()) x.toggleState();}
}

public void on() throws UserErrorException{
    if(state) throw new IllegalStateException();
    this.curEvent = new IND();
    ChronoTimer1009System.globalTime = new Time(0);
    state = true;
}

public void reset() throws UserErrorException{
    if(state) state = false;
    on();
}

public void exit(){
    this.curEvent = null;
    ChronoTimer1009System.globalTime = null;
    if(!state) throw new IllegalStateException();
    state = false;
}

public static Time searchElapsedByID(int idNum){
    Time toReturn = null;
    for(Log item : log){
        if(item.getCompetitorNumber() == idNum){
            toReturn = item.getElapsedTime(); break;
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}

/**
 * @return the curEvent
 */
public Event getCurEvent() {
    return curEvent;
}

/**
 * @return the state
 */
public boolean isState() {
    return state;
}

public static Channel getChan(int chan){
    if(chan < 1 || chan > 8) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is not in range");
    return channels[chan-1];
}

public static void export(){
    //*****FORMAT JSON*****
    //before formating, a sort of the runners within each heat is needed to determine place.
    String toJson = "{\"events\":[";
    System.out.println(ChronoTimer1009System.getMasterLog().get(0).getHeats().get(0).getRacers().size());
    //iterate through each event
    for(int i = 0; i < ChronoTimer1009System.getMasterLog().size(); ++i){
        //iterate through each heat of each event
        toJson += "{\"name\":\"" + ChronoTimer1009System.getMasterLog().get(i).getType().toString() + "\",\"heats\":[";
        for(int j = 0; j < ChronoTimer1009System.getMasterLog().get(i).getHeats().size(); ++j){
            //iterate through each competitor in each heat
            toJson += "{\"runners\":[";
            System.out.println(ChronoTimer1009System.getMasterLog().get(i).getHeats().size());
            ArrayList<Competitor> x = sortByPlace(ChronoTimer1009System.getMasterLog().get(i).getHeats().get(j).getRacers()); <----- on this line, the getRacers() part has a size of zero when it isn't empty.
            for(int k = 0; k < x.size(); ++k){
                //notice we are working with a sorted copy
                //TODO make Competitor endTime the elapsed time
                toJson += "{\"place\":\"" + String.valueOf(k+1) + "\",\"compNum\":\"" + x.get(k).getIdNum() + "\", \"elapsed\":\"" + x.get(k).getEndTime().toString() + "\"},";
            }
            toJson += "]},";
        }
        toJson += "]},";
    }

    toJson += "}";

    System.out.println(toJson);

    /*try{
        URL site = new URL("http://7-dot-eastern-cosmos-92417.appspot.com/chronoserver");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) site.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        String data = "data=" + toJson;
        out.writeBytes(data);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Done sent to server");

        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
}

private static ArrayList<Competitor> sortByPlace(ArrayList<Competitor> unsorted)
{
    ArrayList<Competitor> whole = (ArrayList<Competitor>) unsorted.clone();

    ArrayList<Competitor> left = new ArrayList<Competitor>();
    ArrayList<Competitor> right = new ArrayList<Competitor>();
    int center;

    if(whole.size()==1)    
        return whole;
    else
    {
        center = whole.size()/2;
        // copy the left half of whole into the left.
        for(int i=0; i<center; i++)
        {
                left.add(whole.get(i));
        }

        //copy the right half of whole into the new arraylist.
        for(int i=center; i<whole.size(); i++)
        {
                right.add(whole.get(i));
        }

        // Sort the left and right halves of the arraylist.
        left  = sortByPlace(left);
        right = sortByPlace(right);


        // Merge the results back together.
        merge(left,right,whole);

    }
    return whole;
}

private static void merge(ArrayList<Competitor> left, ArrayList<Competitor> right, ArrayList<Competitor> whole) {

    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;
    int wholeIndex = 0;


    // As long as neither the left nor the right arraylist has
    // been used up, keep taking the smaller of left.get(leftIndex)
    // or right.get(rightIndex) and adding it at both.get(bothIndex).
    while (leftIndex < left.size() && rightIndex < right.size())
    {
        if ((left.get(leftIndex).getEndTime().compareTo(right.get(rightIndex)))<0) 
        {
            whole.set(wholeIndex,left.get(leftIndex));
            leftIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
            whole.set(wholeIndex, right.get(rightIndex));
            rightIndex++;
        }
        wholeIndex++;
    }

    ArrayList<Competitor>rest;
    int restIndex;
    if (leftIndex >= left.size()) {
        // The left arraylist has been use up...
        rest = right;
        restIndex = rightIndex;
    }
    else {
        // The right arraylist has been used up...
        rest = left;
        restIndex = leftIndex;
    }

    // Copy the rest of whichever arraylist (left or right) was
    // not used up.
    for (int i=restIndex; i<rest.size(); i++) {
        whole.set(wholeIndex, rest.get(i));
        wholeIndex++;
    }
}

/**
 * @return the log
 */
public static Stack<Log> getLog() {
    return log;
}

/**
 * @return the masterLog
 */
public static ArrayList<Event> getMasterLog() {
    return masterLog;
}

/**
 * @return the p
 */
public static Printer getPrinter() {
    return p;
}
}
```

Event Class:

```
package main;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Event extends Display{

private ArrayList<Heat> heats;
private int curHeat; //private means only this class can modify, not the subclasses
private Competitor curComp;
private String name;

public Event(String name) throws UserErrorException{
    this.name = name;
    heats = new ArrayList<Heat>();
    curHeat = -1;
    curComp = null;
    createRun();
}

/**
 * This method will be used by all EventTypes and will not change
 * regardless of the EventType.
 * @throws UserErrorException
 */
public void createRun() throws UserErrorException{
    heats.add(new Heat()); ++curHeat;
}

/**
 * @return the heats
 */
public ArrayList<Heat> getHeats() {
    return heats;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @return the currentHeat
 */
public int getCurHeat() {
    return curHeat;
}

/**
 * @return the curComp
 */
public Competitor getCurComp() {
    return curComp;
}

/**
 * @param curComp the curComp to set
 */
public void setCurComp(Competitor curComp) {
    this.curComp = curComp;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see Display#displayHeatNumber()
 */
@Override
public String displayHeatNumber() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "Heat: " + (curHeat+1);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see Display#displayFinished()
 */
@Override
public String displayFinished() {
    String toReturn = "";
    boolean noRunners = true;
    for(Competitor x : getHeats().get(getCurHeat()).getRacers()){
        if(x.getEndTime() != null){
            toReturn += "\n" + x.getIdNum() + " " + (ChronoTimer1009System.searchElapsedByID(x.getIdNum()).equals(new Time(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)) ? "DNF" : ChronoTimer1009System.searchElapsedByID(x.getIdNum()).toString() + " F");
            noRunners = false;
        }
    }
    if(noRunners){toReturn = "no runners have finished";}
    return toReturn;
}

public abstract void endRun() throws UserErrorException;

public abstract void trigChan(int chan, boolean dnf) throws UserErrorException;

public abstract void cancel(int ln) throws UserErrorException;

public abstract EventType getType();
}
```

Heat class:

```
package main;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Heat {

private ArrayList<Competitor> racers;
//private ArrayList<Competitor> racers;
private int currentCompetitor;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public Heat(){
    racers = new ArrayList<Competitor>();
    //racers = new ArrayList<Competitor>();
    currentCompetitor = 0;
}
/**
 * Set selected racer as next on to start
 * @param racer the racer to start next
 */
public void setNextCompetitor(Competitor x){
    int pos = racers.indexOf(x);
    if(pos == -1 || pos<currentCompetitor) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Competitor not in the race! Please add first");
    for(int i = pos; i>currentCompetitor; --i){
        racers.set(i, racers.get(i-1));
    }
    racers.set(currentCompetitor, x);

}
/**
 * Take the selected runner (the next runner) out from the race
 * @param racer the runner to be cleared
 */
public void clearNextCompetitor() throws UserErrorException {
    if(racers.size()-(currentCompetitor)<1) throw new UserErrorException("No runners to clear!");
    for(int i = currentCompetitor+1; i<racers.size(); ++i){
        racers.set(i-1, racers.get(i));
    }
    racers.remove(racers.size()-1);
}
/**
 * basically a remove method
 * @param x
 */
public void remove(Competitor x){
    int pos = racers.indexOf(x);
    if(pos < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("runner does not exists");
    racers.remove(pos);
}

/**
 * Swaps two runners positions in line
 */
public void swap() throws UserErrorException{
    int count = 0;
    for(Competitor x : racers){
        if(x.getStartTime() == null) ++count;
    }
    if(count > 1 && currentCompetitor + 1 <= racers.size()){
        Competitor first = racers.get(currentCompetitor);
        Competitor second = racers.get(currentCompetitor+1);
        racers.set(currentCompetitor, second);
        racers.set(currentCompetitor+1, first);
    }
    else{
        throw new UserErrorException("Not enough competitors to swap");
    }
}
/**
 * Add a competitor to the end of the current line of competitors if any
 * @param x the competitor to add
 */
public boolean addCompetitor(Competitor x) throws UserErrorException{
    if(x.getIdNum() < 0 || x.getIdNum() > 99999) throw new UserErrorException("ID number out of range");
    if(x.getRunNum() < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Run Num Out of range");
    boolean add = true;
    for(Competitor i : racers){
        if(i.getIdNum() == x.getIdNum()){
            add = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(add){
        racers.add(x);  
    }
    return add;
}
/**
 * Retrieve the next competitor if there is one
 * @return the next competitor
 */
public Competitor getNextCompetitor() throws UserErrorException{
    if(!hasNextCompetitor()) throw new UserErrorException("There are no more competitors!");
    while(racers.get(currentCompetitor).isCompeting()){++currentCompetitor;}
    return racers.get(currentCompetitor++);
}
/**
 * used to fix the order of the queue after cancel is called
 */
public void fix(EventType x){
    switch(x){
    case IND: 
        --currentCompetitor;
    break;

    case GRP: case PARGRP: case PARIND:
        for(int i = 0; i<racers.size(); ++i){
            if(racers.get(i).getStartTime() == null){
                currentCompetitor = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    break;
    }
}
/**
 * Is there another competitor to go?
 * @return whether or not there is another competitor to go.
 */
public boolean hasNextCompetitor(){
    return currentCompetitor < racers.size();
}
/**
 * Return a 1D array view of the competitors
 * @return
 */
public ArrayList<Competitor> getRacers(){
    return racers;
}
}
```

in the export method of the ChronoTimer1009System class, I point out where the error is and what is happening

Comment: I changed by masterLog (which was an ArrayList) to a Vector but it still isn't  syncing (updating )

Comment: @Frank don't do that. That's bad advice. Vector should not be used anymore, period. We don't even know if you have a threading problem: you posted no code at all. Post the relevant code (the 3 classes), and a use-case reproducing the problem. We can't find bugs in unknown code.

Comment: Alright I added those classes